# Convert this raw sql to django query

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

hi im trying to convert this sql code into django query

```
select * from KnowledgeManagement_tblknowledge where (14010705 - CreateDate) >=10000 and (register_status = 7 or register_status = 9)
```

I have done a part of it

```
    knowledges = TblKnowledge.objects.filter(Status__gte=0).filter(Q(register_status=7) | Q(register_status=9))
```

but this part seems to be a little tricky

```
where (14010705 - CreateDate) >=10000
```

BTW CreateDate is an integer filed and saves the current date in solar date
and 14010705  is a solar date 14010705 = 1401/07/05

Comment: Regarding the "tricky" part. You should rephrace that predicate to (14010705-10000) >= CreateDate. I guess it will be easier to formulate in django, and it will be easier for the optimizer to utilice indexes on CreateDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your expression. 14000705 is a hardcoded value, yes?

Equivalent operations: `x - y >= z` is the same as `x >= y + z`, `y <= x - z`, or `y + z <= x`.

So, `(14010705 - CreateDate) >= 10000` is equivalent to `14010705 + 10000 <= CreateDate`, or `14020705 <= CreateDate`. And if you want to flip the side: `CreateDate > 14020705`.

So:

```
TblKnowledge.objects.filter(CreateDate__gt=14020705)
```